# angular-ui ui-select-choices is not taking 100 % of the width in IE 9

Tags: angular-ui, angular-ui-select

using the bootstrap theme the ul with class ui-select-choices is not taking 100 % of the width in IE 9. Any idea on how to fix this?

[image]

Answer (score 1):

```
<!--[if ie 9]>
        <style type="text/css">
        .ui-select-bootstrap > .ui-select-choices {
            width: auto;
            min-width: 100%;
        }
    </style>
<![endif]-->
```